# Optimal way for finding index of 'greatest value less than' in Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, sorting, numpy

I have a sorted numpy array `X` and also two constants `k` and `delta` that are not in `X`. I would like to find the index corresponding to, the largest value in `X` less than or equal to `k` and the value must be within `delta` of `k` i.e. I want

```
max {i | k - delta <= X[i] <= k }    (1)
```

Note this set may be empty in which case I will return `None`. The way I'm doing it I currently feel is unoptimal as it doesn't take advantage of the fact `X` is ordered at the first step

```
# Get the max from the set of indices in X satisfying (1)
idx = np.where((k-delta <= X) * (X <= k))[0].max()
```

I'm not sure how clever Numpy can be when doing this as it doesn't already know `X` is sorted hence the `(k-delta <= X) * (X <= k))` will I assume take longer than necessary. Note we can use the `.max()` as we know ourselves the array is sorted.

What would be a more optimal way of doing this?

Comment: You say the array is sorted. So isn't the element that satisfies your condition will always be in the index before `k`? That fact greatly simplifies the solution.

Comment: Yes but `k` is not in `X` so I must first do a comparison between `k` and the elements n `X`

Comment: I see. It's important to note that `k` isn't necessarily in `X`. You might want to clarify it in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One efficient approach to leverage the sorted order would be with [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
def largest_within_delta(X, k, delta):
    right_idx = X.searchsorted(k,'right')-1
    if (k - X[right_idx]) <= delta:
        return right_idx
    else:
        return None
```

Sample runs to cover various scenarios -

```
In [216]: X
Out[216]: array([ 8,  9, 33, 35, 36, 37, 44, 45, 71, 81])

In [217]: largest_within_delta(X, 36, 0) # this k is already in array
Out[217]: 4

In [218]: largest_within_delta(X, 36, 1) # shouldn't choose for next one 37
Out[218]: 4    

In [220]: largest_within_delta(X, 40, 3) # Gets 37's index
Out[220]: 5

In [221]: largest_within_delta(X, 40, 2) # Out of 37's reach
```

**Runtime test**

```
In [212]: # Inputs
     ...: X = np.unique(np.random.randint(0,1000000,(10000)))
     ...: k = 50000
     ...: delta = 100
     ...: 

In [213]: %timeit np.where((k-delta <= X) * (X <= k))[0].max()
10000 loops, best of 3: 44.6 µs per loop

In [214]: %timeit largest_within_delta(X, k, delta)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.22 µs per loop
```

Comment: I like this, just a quick note that to answer the question precisely the function should return `right_idx` as opposed to `X[right_idx]`. I'll wait to see if anyone has any speed analysis before accepting.

Comment: @rwolst Updated my post accordingly. Added some timings there.

Answer (score 1):

[`Numpy.argmax`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) could be usefull for taking advantage of the sorted list.

```
import numpy as np
np.argmax(X <= k) if k-d < np.argmax(X <= k) < k+d else None
```

Comment: note that in case of ties `np.argmax` will return the index of the first largest value, but it seems more logical to prefer the last one, also i don't think that `np.argmax` takes advantage of the sorted list